# Tension of twisted beams

Tags: wood, twist, construction

if a wood beam or rafter is twisted, is there a way to un-twist it? Does clamping it down for a certain period of time straighten it?
If not, is it a good idea to bolt it down to force it straight, or will the constant tension cause issues in the future?

In my case, I am building a patio and all my rafters are twisted. Patio surface area is about 30 square maters, and the rafters have 6 meters length and are 120x50 mm thick. It's practically impossible to find rafters this long that are not twisted. The other option is to use 3 meter rafters which you can find straight, but I would prefer them to be continuous until the end.

A picture for reference, (my dimensions are different and I have another row of posts in the middle that support the rafters)

[image]

---

I tried bolting 2 short pieces of wood on the beam, then sliding the rafter in between. Seems to hold well, there's still a bit of twist visible but it's much better than before

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. I think you need to tell us how bad the twist is, or take a couple of photos (I guess of the worst ones) before we can advise. But in general modest amounts of bow, twist and other warps are A) to be expected in many, perhaps most, pieces of construction wood (including shorter than 6m!) and B) can be forced into alignment when a structure is being built. You see this addressed frequently in DIY shows when e.g. a deck is being built, where a slight twist must be worked out (possibly using clamping tricks) before the second end can successfully be attached to a post.

Comment: If the twist is severe in any of them it would of course be best practice not to use those boards. Return to vendor as defective if possible (realities of warped construction wood aside, there *are* standards!) and perhaps source better wood elsewhere. Failing that I would suggest going with the 3m ones and living with the joint; there are established ways of doing this and maintaining strength (even with major load-bearing members). So you don't need to worry that this will compromise strength, it's really only an aesthetic issue.

Comment: Start with 150x75mm* wood. Let it dry until its done twisting, then joint two adjacent edges to a nice 90°, then plane the other faces parallel until you're down to the final dimension required. This will allow you to get a nice square piece out of something that's twisted. *Note, depending on the amount of twist, you might need to start with even larger lumber.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have the tools to joint or plane such long pieces of wood. I would need some industrial grade jointer for that.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Good to see the suggested solution had a good effect.

Comment: If you're building something in future from any sort of construction wood are you aware of some of the buying tricks to help avoid having to deal with this level of distortion? I think there's an Answer or two with some of the common advice, I can hunt one or both down for you if you need it.

Comment: Usually I pick the wood personally (i don't order it online), so I can check the twist.. but in all places where I have been long beams with half width always have some twist, and even if I buy the ones with the least twist, once I bring them home and leave them for a while they twist much worse. The only pieces of wood I have found without twist are beams that are joined together with teeth and glue. Those can be even at 20 meters lengths. But not sure how well they hold compared to non-glued ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward fix I can think of is to install solid blocking (same dimensions as rafters) at the top and near the bottom of the run. This will mostly force the twist out. (There might be a tiny bit of creep, but it shouldn’t be noticeable.)

Depending on your aesthetic choices, you can stagger the blocking around a line (easier to nail) or line them up exactly (requires toenailing).

Oh, and to answer your initial question: there isn’t much you can do to twisted wood to make it into something flat.